# How can I show/hide background drawing on QGraphicsScene or QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, drawing, qgraphicsscene

I would like to have certain things drawn on QGraphicsScene, but not be QGraphicsItem (it would interfere with the processing of the `QGraphicsItem` collection).

Example: a scene bounding rectangle, a grid

I am overriding the `drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)` for that purpose. (I should subclass the scene... )

```
void MyView::showHideBounds()
{
    m_showBackgroundBounds = !m_showBackgroundBounds;
    // can't triger an update ???
    update(); // neither does anything
    viewport()->update();
}

void MyView::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{
    QPen pen;
    if(m_showBackgroundBounds)
        pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 0), 10, Qt::PenStyle(Qt::SolidLine));
    else
        pen = QPen(QColor(255, 255, 255), 10, Qt::PenStyle(Qt::SolidLine));

    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->drawRect(QRect(QPoint(-scene()->sceneRect().size().toSize().width()/2,
                                   -scene()->sceneRect().size().toSize().height()/2),
                            scene()->sceneRect().size().toSize()));
}
```

I would like the option to **show/hide** either the bounding rectangle or the grid.

The only thing I can think of is paint over them with the color of the background brush ? Is there any other option ?

As I have written it above, it works - except I need user action on items (or a zoom or some other scene changing action) to trigger refresh, or call an update... (the function  `showHideBounds` doesn't - not sure how to make it force a refresh)

I would call the `drawBackground` from the  `showHideBounds` function - but I don't know how to get the `painter`

[Also, the `drawBackground` seems to be drawn automatically... how can I give it the `rect` argument it needs ? (it seems if I draw the `rect` it does draw the scene rectangle but I only see the right and bottom edges)]

Comment: This doesn't seem like a reasonable thing to do. It's so much simpler to add every visible object as a graphics item. If it "interferes" with some processing, just fix the processing. For example, you can add a single graphics item representing your items collection and make other items its children.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov Functions like saving (rendering the entire scene) and fitInView (for all scene items bounding rectangle) would be affected - rewriting them to loop through all items to check if items have a parent  or to check a flag, perhaps create a dummy scene copy, would result in big performance impact...

Comment: I don't believe mentioned issues are unsolvable. You could hide unwanted items while rendering if you don't want to see them on result. Bounding rect can be efficiently calculated with `QGraphicsItem::​childrenBoundingRect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to redraw a particular section of scene, you can call

```
QGraphicsScene->invalidate(rect_to_redraw, Backgroundlayer)
```

Note that if `drawBackground(*painter, rect)` paints over area outside rect, it will not update automatically. In that case invalidate has to be called with appropriate rect parameters.